# How did Han modify his weapon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, weapon, laws

Han Solo supposedly illegally modified his [blaster](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DL-44_heavy_blaster_pistol). I can't find a reference on the web for this. If he did, how did he modify it and why was it illegal to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DL-44_heavy_blaster_pistol) reports on its entry for the DL-44, the first blaster we see Solo using:

> The DL-44 was the weapon of choice of the General and Alliance hero,
>   once-smuggler Han Solo, who removed the barrel-sight to facilitate his
>   fast-draw, something that the empire deemed to be an illegal
>   modification of a blaster. In a later era, Jaden Korr, Rosh Penin and
>   other New Jedi Order students carried DL-44 pistols when on missions
>   where a blaster might be neccessary. Mara Jade was also known to carry
>   one of those on occasion. They were also the anti-infantry sidearm of
>   choice for the Rebel vanguards, in addition to their anti-vehicle
>   weaponry.

Comment: Wow, I'm pretty blind.

Comment: He made the modification in the trilogy of books set in the Corporate Sector; The Han Solo adventures I believe, after the sight caught in his holster while he was trying to draw it.

Comment: Is there an actual canon reference for "empire deemed to be an illegal modification of a blaster" bit? That Wikia article is uncited as hell

Answer (score 4):

I recall that he had an encounter with a large lizard-like person in one of the Han Solo Trilogy books, which preceded the original Star Wars trilogy. He tried to draw his blaster, but the barrel sight caught in the holster, leaving him in a bad spot.  I think this was after he had freed Chewbacca, who came to his rescue, and it was this point that they became partners.

Shortly after this incident Han took some time to remove the sight from his blaster, to avoid a similar situation happening again.

Comment: While removing the front sight might sound weird, if you watch Han as he shoots, most of the time it's with a tactic called "point shooting". Secondly, removing the front sight had no effect on the ability of actually aiming the weapon, as the blaster itself had a scope attached to it.