# What firearms regulations exist in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, laws

Was there any regulation of hand-held blasters, slug-throwers and other weapons?

I know that according to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/how-did-han-modify-his-weapon) Han illegally modified his blaster, so surely there are *some* regulations on the modification of blasters. Just to make it clear, I am asking about blasters and other ranged firearms that a single person could hold, not ship mounted lasers ([already asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186152/why-are-the-millennium-falcon-and-other-civilian-vessels-allowed-to-have-ship-mo).)

So what laws governed the use and ownership of blasters, slugthrowers and other ranged weapons in the Star Wars universe?

EDIT: I am asking specifically about regulation during the Rise of the Empire, Rebellion and New Republic eras (From 30BBY - 30ABY.)

Comment: Almost certainly it depended on the Laws of the Planet you were on. Different Planets would have different Laws depending on whether it was a Central High population world (probably restricted) to Frontier worlds where there were little or no government and highly dangerous animals and Native inhabitants who might be hostile. (ie Tatooine where Luke was raised.)

Comment: Also, in which era?

Comment: A well-regulated Jedi Order, being necessary to the security of a free Republic, the right of the people to keep and bear lightsabers, shall not be infringed.

Comment: @Valorum Just updated

Comment: @Boolean - So, basically over the past 1050 years of recorded history on a million planets then?

Comment: @Valorum - OK, i narrowed down the time span

Comment: I edited the title to match your question body. This should be directly answerable with canon citations.

Comment: From what I can see from the movies and legends books, it seems there is no law at all in the Star Wars universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NO DISINTEGRATIONS.*

I'm not sure where this Han 'removed the scope' thing came from. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_(Star_Wars)), Han's was "illegally modified to provide greater damage without increasing power consumption."

IIRC, it's mentioned in the Thrawn series, that **disrupters are illegal**.

> When fired upon a biological target, the victim was disintegrated atom by atom, resulting in a slow, painful death. After T-7's were used against the Lasat during the fall of their homeworld, the weapons were banned by the Imperial Senate. – [**Disruptor**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Disruptor)